# How to fix the button always at the end of the list in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of amenities which is wrapped in a Wrap widget. At the end of the list I have the `Other` button - this button should always be at the end of the list. But I have a problem that when I add a new element to this list, then the `Other` button does not move to the end, but stays on its own together. Can you please tell me how to make sure that when adding new elements, the `Other` button always remains at the end?

**body**

```
Wrap(
   runSpacing: 8,
   children: [
       for (int i = 0; i < defaultAmenities.length; i++) 
         amenityCard(i),
   ],
),




Widget amenityCard(int i) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 6),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          if (defaultAmenities.keys.elementAt(i) == 'Other') {
            setState(() {
              isOther = true;
            });
          } else {
            setState(() {
              if (selectedAmenities
                  .contains(defaultAmenities.keys.elementAt(i))) {
                selectedAmenities.removeWhere(
                  (element) => element == defaultAmenities.keys.elementAt(i),
                );
              } else {
                selectedAmenities.add(defaultAmenities.keys.elementAt(i));
              }
            });
          }

          widget.onAmenitiesChanged(selectedAmenities);
        },
        child: Container(
          width: 20 + defaultAmenities.keys.elementAt(i).length * 13,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          height: 40,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                const SizedBox(width: 3),
                Text(
                  defaultAmenities.keys.elementAt(i),
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: selectedAmenities
                            .contains(defaultAmenities.keys.elementAt(i))
                        ? constants.Colors.green
                        : Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
                    fontFamily: constants.FontFamily.AvenirLtStd,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                    fontSize: 16,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

Map<String, String> defaultAmenities = {
  'Free Wifi': constants.Assets.wifi,
  'Restroom': constants.Assets.amenitiesRestroom,
  'Cafe': constants.Assets.amenitiesCafe,
  'Other': constants.Assets.add,
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is two ways.
first : separating it into 2 lists:

```
Wrap(
   runSpacing: 8,
   children: [
       for (int i = 0; i < defaultAmenities.length; i++) 
         amenityCard(i),
   ] + [ // other ametyCard],
),
```

second :
instead of `add` you can use `insert` at index , index must be list lenght -2, because other is the last index;

```
selectedAmenities.insert(selectedAmenities.lenght -2 ,defaultAmenities.keys.elementAt(i));
```